# C# method/function that returns true or false if a character appears in a string repeatedly

Tags: c#

I need to write a method/function using C# that accepts two parameters: one string and one character. The function should return true if for every instance of the character in the string, there is another instance of the character immediately to the left or right. In other words, the function should return true only if the character appears in the string **only as a pair**. I can't seem to figure it out.

Examples:

```
Manipulation("abcdeefghi", 'e') -> true
Manipulation("abcdeeefghi", 'e') -> false
```

Currently I have:

```
public bool Manipulation(string strParam, char[] charParam)
{
    if (strParam.Contains(charParam))
    {
        return true;                
    }
    return false;
}
```

I already know this doesn't work but I was trying to at least get a return of true if I could find it at least once in the string.

Comment: both parameters should be a string (not char[]).

Comment: @jdweng No. One should be a char and one a string.

Comment: What should f("abcdeeefghi", e) result in? Is it only for *pairs* or also triplets and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way of looking at it would be traversing the string once, just checking if a run of your char appears: Note that this answer requires the `char` to appear exactly twice, for example:

```
IsPairOccurence("abcdeefghi", 'e') -> true
IsPairOccurence("abcdeeefghi", 'e') -> false
```

Checking if it appears *at least* twice is easier, as shown by @aditya's answer.

```
private bool IsPairOccurence(string s, char c) {
    int occurence = 0; // the number of consecutive occurences
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        if (s[i] == c) { // If you encounter the character
            occurrence++; // Increase the counter
        } else { // If another character occurs
            if (occurence == 2) {
            // Check if the number of consecutive occurences was exactly 2
                return true;
            }
            // If not, reset the counter
            occurence = 0;
        }
    }
    return occurence == 2;
}
```

This answer is surprisingly easy to generalise for any case, e.g. if you want to count exactly occurrences of 3 consecutive or 24 consecutive chars. You can even generalise it for `n` consecutive characters:

```
private bool DoesOccurNTimes(string s, char c, int n) {
    int occurence = 0; // the number of consecutive occurences
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        if (s[i] == c) { // If you encounter the character
            occurrence++; // Increase the counter
        } else { // If another character occurs
            if (occurence == n) {
            // Check if the number of consecutive occurences was exactly n
                return true;
            }
            // If not, reset the counter
            occurence = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check for the end of the string
    return occurence == n;
}
```

Now `IsPairOccurence(s, c)` is simply `DoesOccurNTimes(s, c, 2)`.

Comment: When sending the char to this function should it look like this?
string strParam = txtString.Text;
char[] charParam = txtChar.Text.ToCharArray();
bool answer = IsPairOccurence(strParam, charParam);

Comment: This would unfortunately fail for (abcdeeghe, e)

Comment: @Mabbott No, you have to call it with a `char`, not a `char[]`. so pick a character and pass it, for example the first `char` of `charParam`: `IsPairOccurence(strParam, charParam[0])`. This is the only sensible interpretation according to your question.

Comment: @ThreeFx Thank you!

Comment: @aditya Why? What is the expected value? It returning `true` is the correct interpretation IMO.

Comment: It is because it does not have all two occurrences of e. I am not sure still if the question requires all 2 simultaneous occurrences, or finding just 1 and then others being single is alright.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, but as @ThreeFx suggested in the comments you need to mention if it is only for pairs or for triplets and so on as well.

Nevertheless, the answer assumes the latter case:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackQuestionAnswersCS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (checkContains("HelloWorld", 'o')) Console.WriteLine("Contains Character");
            else Console.WriteLine("Does not contain character");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static bool checkContains(string input, char character)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (input[i] == character && input[i+1] == character) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to count, just return true

Comment: @Steve Yes, his code does just fine (as you can see by the return type `bool`). You have to somehow count the characters to determine whether one appears twice.

Comment: Should your code return `true` on `checkContains("abcdeeefghi", 'e')`?

Comment: @Steve, made the correction. I was trying out a different (and more complicated way initially and therefore the count), this is more efficient. Reduces the number of comparisons.

Comment: @ThreeFx, yes as it is not clear in the question, I have assumes one or more simultaneous occurrences to the character in the string

Comment: I'm only looking for it appearing twice.

Comment: I will change my answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static bool Manipulation(string p, char c)
{
   return p.Contains(c.ToString() + c.ToString()) && !p.Replace(c.ToString() + c.ToString(), "").Contains(c);
}
```